# Is it possible to authenticate to app using a pin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

Application backend is on AWS(lambda), to the auth we use Cognito.
We want to be able to log in to the application(mobile) using Cognito via PIN (ten-digit number e.g 9384356392)

Do you know if Cognito offers something like this to handle such a case?
I will be very grateful for all the materials regarding how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have such a use-case by leveraging the `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow in Amazon Cognito. If you use the `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow, you can create your own password logic/requirements for authentication by writing the algorithm in the `DefineAuthChallenge` Lambda trigger.

For more details about the `CUSTOM_AUTH`, please refer to this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-challenge.html).